# GA collect inaccurate user count

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

We are using Google Analytics to Collect Data but we are using the `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?...` method.

The problem is, the user count on the dashboard doesn't seem to be accurate. The pageviews is kinda accurate. Basically, the are way more than pageviews than the number of users.

The `user` variable is unique and being stored in the cookies/

```js
var page = "PageName";
var user = "372055f3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a3ba67b3ee4b";
var obj = {
  v: 1,
  tid: "UA-XXXX-XXXX",
  t: "pageview",
  cid: user,
  uid: user,
  dt: page,
  dp: "/SOMEPATH/OTHER/PATH",
  dl: window.location.href,
  z: user + "-" + Date.now(),
}

var urlParam = [];
for (var k in obj) {
  urlParam.push(k + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[k]));
}

var url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?" + urlParam.join("&");
//Adding the image to the body.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send the same data package (as your example) 5 times, you will have in Google Analytics 1 user and 5 pageviews.
This because it depends on the scope-types, in this case (user or hit).